# How to return to previous key in dictionary given a specific value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have different tax rates for different income levels.

I am trying to return the 'max' value from the tax rate acquired from a function. How can I get it to return to the 'max' value?

```
tax_levels = [
{
    "min": 0,
    "max": 999,
    "rate": 1,
},
{
    "min": 1000,
    "max": 1999,
    "rate": 5
},
]

current_rate = 5
max_current_rate = ??

def max_current_rate(current_rate, tax_levels):
for index, tax_level in enumerate(tax_levels):
    if tax_level['rate'] == current_rate:
        max_current_rate = tax_levels[index]['rate'] #I am trying to 'rate' -1
        return max_current rate
```

I have tried a for loop... trying to make 'rate'-1 in the loop.
I am trying to get it to return to 1999 for max_current_rate using the variable current_rate. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't hesitate to write a simple `for` loop with `if` condition. It's a duplicate, for sure

Comment: What do you have tried so far?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have tried a for loop but isn't working... I've edited my code for your reference

Comment: @Kampi I've tired a for loop

Answer (score 1):

What’s stopping you from grabbing the `max` key out of the current item you’re iterating over?

```
def max_current_rate(current_rate, tax_levels):
    for index, tax_level in enumerate(tax_levels):
        if tax_level['rate'] == current_rate:
            max_current_rate = tax_level['max']
            return max_current_rate
```

In the loop, `tax_level` will be one of the dicts, so you have access to both its `rate` and `max` values.

Comment: the 'max' key is in fact a function called over... e.g. criteria().
criteria() will be 'rate' in this case

Comment: What do you mean by a ‘function called over’? Do you mean that the function is used to generate a value for the key?

Comment: yes, that is right. A function was used to generate 'rate'

Comment: If your list `tax_levels` is in the same form, the code should still work. If not, please edit your question to show the detailed format of your list of dicts.

Comment: When criteria() = 'rate'
How can I transform tax_level[criteria()] such that it will eventually become tax_level['max'] in this case?

Comment: Are you relying on the insertion order of dictionaries? This is Python 3.6+

Comment: No, i am currently not. Do i need it for it to work?

Comment: Yes. You are assuming the dict has an order where keys are ordered. They are ordered in Python 3.6+ only. If not, you need to create a list of keys `keys = ['min', 'max', 'rate']`. Then to grab the previous key, use `tax_level[keys[keys.index(criteria()) - 1]]`. This finds the index of whatever `criteria()` returns and then use the one before it. This is as opposed to hard-coding the keys to check.

Comment: I think i got it figured out with the ordereddict! thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure if I understand your question and your problem correct. I assume that you want to get the highest `rate` value in your `tax_levels`. So you need to properly process `List` with `Dicts`:

```
tax_levels = [
{
    "min": 0,
    "max": 999,
    "rate": 1
},
{
    "min": 1000,
    "max": 1999,
    "rate": 5
},
]

current_rate = 5

def Func(Rate, TaxLevels):
  for Level in TaxLevels:
      if Level['rate'] == Rate:
          return Level['rate']

print(Func(current_rate, tax_levels))
```

This code results in

```
>> 5
```